# Accessing Non static members from a static method. I get error as - cannot make a static reference to a non-static field

Tags: java

Below code gives the error as - cannot make a static reference to a non-static field. Though non-static members can be accessed from a static method using object of the class. Can you please suggest.

```
package dataTypes;

public class CharDemo {

    CharDemo cd = new CharDemo();;

    char defaultCharValue;

    static void defaultCharValue() {            
        System.out.println("Default char value from static instance method is "+cd.defaultCharValue); //--error
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {                                
        System.out.println("Default char value is "+cd.defaultCharValue);//error    
    }    
}
```

Comment: you have to make cd static. Now it is not static but you reference it from a static method.

Comment: Hint: it's not `defaultCharValue` that's causing the problem, it's `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call not-static context into static block directly.
Because static context is associated with class and not-static is associated with object.
All static members gets memory at the time of class loading in method area and all non-static gets memory at the time of object creation i.e in heap area.

> Hence, Java does not allow to use non-static context in static context directly you need to access it with the help of object.

Here above cd causes problem as it is non-static and you are trying to access directly in static block.

> You have to do something like this :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
     CharDemo ch = new CharDemo();                     
    System.out.println("Default char value is "+ch.cd.defaultCharValue);//error    
}
```